# Strange characters (^[[A) on Cygwin command line when I SSH into a Ubuntu VM

Tags: command-line, ssh

Up arrow produces

```
^[[A
```

and down arrow produces

```
^[[B
```

These look like ASCI escape codes. I don't get this problem when I am working outside of the SSH session. Also, when I `sudo su` in the SSH session to a different user I do not have this issue. It seems I may have some problems with my Ubuntu user account?

Comment: what is the user's login shell? you can check with `getent passwd $USER`

Comment: `username:x:1001:1001::/home/username:/bin/sh`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be running the `dash` shell (`/bin/sh` is a symbolic link to `dash` in the standard Ubuntu install). The default dash shell does not include support for inline editing or command history, so the arrow keys are not bound to the familiar edit/history functions and just appear in the terminal as raw keycodes.

Try changing your Ubuntu user's login shell to bash

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

and then starting a new SSH session.

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain why this worked?

Comment: I added a bit of explanation to the answer

Comment: The `chsh` tools allows users to modify the login shell assigned to them in /etc/passwd.  In Debian and Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is now Dash, designed as the system shell but not very pretty for interactive use.  The default shell for regular users is normally `/bin/bash`.  As for how you ended up with `/bin/sh` as your shell I don't know.